# Class with Struct Inside of it is not Instantiating (Segmentation-Faults Right Away)

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault, queue

What I believe I'm doing is implementing a queue using a circular linked list. It segmentation-faults as soon as I instantiate a Queue object. Researched the issue, but at this point, I've got no idea what's really going wrong, but I'm positive it's got something to do with that Queue class.

I have a Queue class to manage the operations of the queue and a QueueNode struct inside the Queue class to represent a node. The functions in the queue class are supposed to work with the struct objects. I stripped everything down to the smallest amount of code to make the problem minimally reproducible.

I have one class specification file, one class implementation file and one main function. Would really love some help.

```
#ifndef queue_hpp
#define queue_hpp

class Queue
{

    struct QueueNode
    {
        QueueNode *next;
        QueueNode *prev;
        int val;
        QueueNode(int valueOne)
        {
            val = valueOne;
            next = nullptr;
            prev = nullptr;
        }

    };


    QueueNode *head;

    public: 
        Queue();
        ~Queue();   //Frees all memory of nodes in the queue
};


#endif
```

```
//Implementation file#include "queue.hpp"
#include <iostream>



/**********************************************************************************
** Queue constructor. Initializes head to null;
**********************************************************************************/
Queue::Queue()
{
    head = nullptr;
    head->prev = head;
    head->next = head;

}


/**********************************************************************************
** Queue Destructor. Handles memory deallocation as queue goes out of scope
**********************************************************************************/
Queue::~Queue()
{


}
```

```
#include "queue.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using std::endl;
using std::cout;


int main()
{

    Queue firstQueue;

    cout << "Queue is created!" << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably should read something about debugging your code, and try to step through it. It will allow you to see where your code segfaults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Queue` constructor you set `head` to `nullptr` and then in next line you're trying to dereference it. Dereferencing `nullptr` is undefined behaviour and can result in segmentation fault.